# Can the sql query in Tilestache cfg vector layer have variables passed in as parameters?

Tags: tilestache

Something like this such that a variable is passed in as a parameter:

```
"vector": {
      "allowed origin": "*",
            "provider": {
            "class": "TileStache.Goodies.VecTiles:Provider",
            "kwargs": {
                "dbinfo": {
                    "host": "localhost",
                    "user": "postgres",
                    "database": "mydb"
                },
                "queries": [
                    "SELECT something_interesting, geometry AS __geometry__ FROM mydb where something_interesting > [**variable**]"
                ]
            }
        }            
    }
```

If not, what's the best approach to take?  The idea is to be able to dynamically view and interact with postGIS data?  I know this perhaps defeats the ability to cache the json tiles.